# The illegal characters in file names

Tags: php, rename, iconv

Image names in the '?' I can not change the character with the PHP rename function.
str_replace function did not work either.

What is the solution?

[sample pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXbUA.jpg)
[image]

I used functions;

```
function replace($title){ 

    $text = trim($title);
    $search = array('Ç','ç','Ğ','ğ','ı','İ','Ö','ö','Ş','ş','Ü','ü',' ','%','?');
    $replace = array('c','c','g','g','i','i','o','o','s','s','u','u','_','_','-');
    $new_text = str_replace($search,$replace,$text);
    $value = preg_replace("@[^A-Za-z0-9-_]+@i","",$new_text);

    return $value;
}
```

I tried the iconv function, but it was illegal character error.

Comment: do you know what's the original charset ?

Answer (score 1):

Your function working correctly, when i call your function like this `echo replace("MaÇsoÖ");`